# Bootstrap cols height causes next line to start in the wrong place

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looping my list of items and each item has `<div class="col-md-4">` which makes it to 3 items each row. There are total of 6 records in my template.

My problem is that in the second line some items starts right after the first line of blocks, and some items start in the end of the second line of the blocks. What's wrong?

This is an illustration of how my template is:

[image]

And this is the desired result:

[image]

Will be fine if they starts right after the first line, without any space.

Any ideas?

- It is a problem for me to check for number of items and use `</div><div class="row">`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using the right structure to do this as given below:

```
    <div class="container"> //can be container-fluid also depending on need

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>

            .. so on

        </div>


    </div>
```

Modified structure: (see if this can meet your requirements)

```
  <div class="container"> 

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;" >asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:150px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;" >asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;" >asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                    <li style="height:100px; border:1px solid #333;">asd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes I do. Check it out with different heighted div's.

Comment: You may need to close row tags after every 3 col-mds then

Comment: Check my edit if that helps